# Improving image quality of CSS-downscaled elements

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

I'm zooming out the contents of my awesome graph editor using [`transform: scale(x)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale). When zooming-out the scale goes down towards `0` (exclusive), when zooming-in the scale goes up, up to a maximum of `1` (inclusive) which means full zoom or initial scale.

However, when zoomed-out considerably, **image quality starts becoming really noisy** -- please consider the following example, and notice how zooming out will make image appearance noisy:

```js
var graphContainer = document.getElementById("graph-container");
var zoomInButton = document.getElementById("zoom-in-button");
var zoomOutButton = document.getElementById("zoom-out-button");
var zoomLevel = 1;

zoomInButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    zoomLevel = Math.max(1, zoomLevel - 0.25);
    graphContainer.style.transform = "scale(" + (1 / zoomLevel) + ")";
});

zoomOutButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    zoomLevel = zoomLevel + 0.25;
    graphContainer.style.transform = "scale(" + (1 / zoomLevel) + ")";
});
```

```css
#editor-container {
    background-color: #001723;
}

#graph-container { transform-origin: top center; }
```

```html
<div id="editor-container">
    <button id="zoom-in-button">Zoom in</button>
    <button id="zoom-out-button">Zoom out</button>
    <div id="graph-container">
        <img class="shape" src="http://i.imgur.com/zsWkcGz.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo also on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wrekhadk/1/)

*This image is a canvas-drawn shape that interactively visualizes a connection between two graph nodes, exported into png.*

---

Please zoom out and see how noisy that line is, even though zooming is done in steps of `0.25` and with CSS. **How can I get rid of this pixel-noise?** The issue happens in both the latest Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge, untested in other browsers. The issue happens with and without 3D GPU acceleration.

> **Note:** obviously, this is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the real work is magnitudes more complex.
>
> Hundrends of line shapes are drawn procedurally onto a canvas (<1ms per line) and then cached to `img` elements asynchronously using [toDataUrl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) (~40ms per line) when idle, so that screen panning -- which is also a required feature -- works more smoothly, as moving an `img` element on the screen is much cheaper than moving a `canvas` element (or redrawing all lines on a single canvas), whether it's the element itself, the container, or the browser viewport that is translated into a given direction.
>
> As such, **generating mipmaps is not really an option, or only as a last resort**, as it will come with a *significant* performance penalty (each mip-level would have to be cached onto a separate image, cutting performance in half at the very least). I'd like to believe it can be avoided, though. Redrawing line shapes on each zoom step will mercillesly obliterate performance down to a slideshow.

The following is the list of things I tried, no effect:

- Hinting at better image quality by defining the following CSS property values, on the shapes elements itself, or the container:

```auto
image-rendering: pixelated | optimizeSpeed | optimizeQuality
```

- Forcing elevating the rendering layer into GPU acceleration with a dummy `transform`
- Using `scale3d` instead of `scale`
- Halving `img.width` and `img.height` and then compensating by doubling `img.style.width` and `img.style.height`
- Not caching canvas results into `img` and instead displaying the `canvas` element directly (slower performance, same bad quality)

I also tried using `filter: blur` when zoomed out, but it [did not yield a better quality](https://jsfiddle.net/wrekhadk/2/), as the blur effect itself is applied *after* the given shape has been rendered on screen.

**What else can I do to get rid of this pixel-noise, besides creating downsampled versions of each shape, effectively creating a software-rendered mipmap (LOD) system?** (which, as I wrote, would like to *strongly* avoid)

---

*How is this question different from the array of [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=image+downscale+quality) investigating bad image quality from downscaling?*

- *Here, it's the container that is downscaled (and with CSS transformations), instead of individual image elements. No manipulation is done to actual image data, which is what is discussed in similar topics.*

Comment: I think "PNG" image also raster image that's why image quality doesn't look proper while it zooming. Did you try this with vector format image. ?

Comment: use scalable vector graphic instead of raster image or u can draw it on canvas.

Comment: @Smile0ff I'm drawing these shapes to a canvas (please look at note, hundreds of them), and only then are the canvas results cached to `img` elements -- otherwise, moving contents on screen is really bad. Doing a redraw on each zoom would instantly obliterate performance down to a slideshow.

Comment: @SayedRafeeq Each of these shapes are drawn on a `canvas`, from which the results are then exported to `img.src` using `toDataUrl` to improve the performance of screen panning in my application.

Comment: I do not see any pixel-noise in Chromium. Version 48.0.2564.82 Ubuntu 15.04 (64-bit).

Comment: Why do you think would make a difference if you're setting image dimensions or using transforms? This question is indeed not different from similar questions at all. If setting the image-rendering attribute doesnt help, you can only try to use a bigger image to begin with, eg. for a 200x200px target resolution use a 400x400px image, and the downsampled outcome should be smoother at non integer scales.

Comment: How pixel images scale down will also vary from one OS to the other and one browser to the other. I did a test on MBP - Retina and standard screen (Firefox and Safari). It looks alright to me (try zoom): http://imgur.com/a/E2l2B

Comment: toDataURL is definitely dlower than drawing even a thousand shapes. You've got a desifn problem. Don't move the canvas, redraw it. And for even less work to the computer, draw it once on a big offscreen canvas then use drawImage(offscrennCanvas, x, y) if you just need to pan it.

Comment: @Kaiido The thing is, hundreds of these lines can be present in the editor area, and each line is drawn on a separate canvas as otherwise if a node (lines go between nodes) is moved, every single line would have to be redrawn. Also, _moving_ the canvas itself instead of doing a redraw when the line distance does not change (only its position) turned out to be faster in this setup. Nevertheless, that's a good suggestion.

Comment: I personally think that SVG would be the way to go here. *Scalable* Vector Graphics and all that. The demo you've provided is a simple `path` with one Bézier curve tipped with a `marker-end` arrowhead, for instance.

Comment: @j4k3 A bigger image would only provide more noise, and downsampling is not really an option for me.

Comment: @john-white You _are_ already downsampling, client-sided, if you're displaying the image at a different size than it's rendered.

Comment: @JohnWhite, if you've got a way to show us this editor, then we may be able to help you better, because once again, you've got a design problem. `toDataURL` in itself is the slowest method available in the whole Canvas2D API, add to that the fact that the browser needs to actually parse the dataURL and render it, that it has to create a lot of DOM elements, that it has to repaint everything around these and you've got an horrible workflow. If your shapes are not going to be modified too much, then yes as others has pointed out svg may be a solution, but keep in mind that browser will have ...

Comment: ... to repaint anyway, and that canvas drawings are also vector drawings, so you can stick with canvas without too much apprehension. Panning and downscaling can be made on canvas without being resource intensive quite easily with `drawImage()` which is just a copy pixel operation, hardware accelerated, and less intensive than any CSS repaint. If you need to up-scale, then you'll need to redraw, but when done correctly (avoid `save()`, use `fill()` only once for each color etc.), you can draw **thousands** of shapes each frame without making your fan spin faster than in idle.

Comment: @Kaiido I greatly appreciate your suggestions, I will consider the refactoring you described. One problem I can think of with this approach is that most elements in the app, lines and nodes (which are connected by lines) are interactive with the pointer. That is, a line or node is highlighted when the pointer enters its area, as well as a node takes a different shape (animated) when selected by clicking. I didn't include these details in the question, as in its current form this is hardly an xy problem IMO, more like a design decision considering several dozen factors.

Comment: I recomend you to use svg files instead of png... that will help you.
If you need some extra behaviour with graphs I strong recommend you https://d3js.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get much better results using SVG images instead of PNG and they are also very easy to generate and embed in your code, you don't even need to host them.

As you can see in this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vo5ox0r2/) the SVG won't pixelate or become blurry and you will get even better results in high resolution screens like the Retina ones.

**The SVG code:**

```
<svg class="shape" width="440px" height="319px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <path d="M1,316.040132 C1,316.040132 241.5837,339.680482 241.5837,163.497447 C241.5837,-12.6855883 439,2.31775322 439,2.31775322" id="Path" stroke="#50E3C2" stroke-width="2"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Obviously is not perfect.

Answer (score 2):

The interpolation of an image with sharp edge will inevitably create artifacts. Even if it is antialised, even if it is blured. You can test this in Photoshop itself, you'll get the same result.

Even the mipmap approach won't work.

The inherent problem is that pixels aren't able to retain all the information of your complex vector shapes; and when you squeeze pixels, shapes get lost. There are two solutions to improve the quality:

- either render the picture at a higher resolution before scaling it so there's more pixels to store the intent of your shape
- or directly render your vector shapes at the scale you're aiming

Comment: It indeed seems I'll need to go with a different approach and cut some interaction features. BTW, with the mipmap approach, I increase the `scale` size of the actual shape proportionally, thus never actually scaling the shape below `0.5` of its original size. Visually it produces a very high quality image, but it is very performance demanding because of all the recaching that has to be done.